# Kubernetes Ingress-controller ssl passthrough without termination

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I use kubernetes 1.11.4 for ssl passthrough without termination to worker nodes. There are one deployment with two pods on each worker node
I use ingress controller as daemonset

```
    ##TODO Set up custom default backend

    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Namespace
    metadata:
      name: ingress-nginx

    ---

    kind: ConfigMap
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: nginx-configuration
      namespace: ingress-nginx
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

    ---
    kind: ConfigMap
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: tcp-services
      namespace: ingress-nginx
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

    ---
    kind: ConfigMap
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: udp-services
      namespace: ingress-nginx
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ServiceAccount
    metadata:
      name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
      namespace: ingress-nginx
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

    ---
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: ClusterRole
    metadata:
      name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        resources:
          - configmaps
          - endpoints
          - nodes
          - pods
          - secrets
        verbs:
          - list
          - watch
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        resources:
          - nodes
        verbs:
          - get
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        resources:
          - services
        verbs:
          - get
          - list
          - watch
      - apiGroups:
          - "extensions"
        resources:
          - ingresses
        verbs:
          - get
          - list
          - watch
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        resources:
          - events
        verbs:
          - create
          - patch
      - apiGroups:
          - "extensions"
        resources:
          - ingresses/status
        verbs:
          - update

    ---
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Role
    metadata:
      name: nginx-ingress-role
      namespace: ingress-nginx
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        resources:
          - configmaps
          - pods
          - secrets
          - namespaces
        verbs:
          - get
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        resources:
          - configmaps
        resourceNames:
          # Defaults to "<election-id>-<ingress-class>"
          # Here: "<ingress-controller-leader>-<nginx>"
          # This has to be adapted if you change either parameter
          # when launching the nginx-ingress-controller.
          - "ingress-controller-leader-nginx"
        verbs:
          - get
          - update
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        resources:
          - configmaps
        verbs:
          - create
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        resources:
          - endpoints
        verbs:
          - get

    ---
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: RoleBinding
    metadata:
      name: nginx-ingress-role-nisa-binding
      namespace: ingress-nginx
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    roleRef:
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      kind: Role
      name: nginx-ingress-role
    subjects:
      - kind: ServiceAccount
        name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
        namespace: ingress-nginx

    ---
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: ClusterRoleBinding
    metadata:
      name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole-nisa-binding
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    roleRef:
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      kind: ClusterRole
      name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole
    subjects:
      - kind: ServiceAccount
        name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
        namespace: ingress-nginx

    ---

    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: DaemonSet
    metadata:
      name: nginx-ingress-controller
      namespace: ingress-nginx
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
          app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
            app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
          annotations:
            prometheus.io/port: "10254"
            prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        spec:
          nodeSelector:
            role: edge-router
          serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
          containers:
            - name: nginx-ingress-controller
              image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.21.0
              args:
                - /nginx-ingress-controller
                - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
                - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
                - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
                - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
                - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
                - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
    #            - --enable-ssl-passthrough=true
    #            - --enable-access-log=true
    #            - --enable-dynamic-certificates=true
              securityContext:
                capabilities:
                  drop:
                    - ALL
                  add:
                    - NET_BIND_SERVICE
                # www-data -> 33
                runAsUser: 33
              env:
                - name: POD_NAME
                  valueFrom:
                    fieldRef:
                      fieldPath: metadata.name
                - name: POD_NAMESPACE
                  valueFrom:
                    fieldRef:
                      fieldPath: metadata.namespace
              ports:
                - name: http
                  containerPort: 80
                - name: https
                  containerPort: 443
              livenessProbe:
                failureThreshold: 3
                httpGet:
                  path: /healthz
                  port: 10254
                  scheme: HTTP
                initialDelaySeconds: 10
                periodSeconds: 10
                successThreshold: 1
                timeoutSeconds: 1
              readinessProbe:
                failureThreshold: 3
                httpGet:
                  path: /healthz
                  port: 10254
                  scheme: HTTP
                periodSeconds: 10
                successThreshold: 1
                timeoutSeconds: 1

    ---
 I set up controller in separate worker node switched to drain mode
This is code for deployment and service

    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: meteo
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: meteo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: meteo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: meteo
        image: devprofi/meteo:v11
        ports:
          - containerPort: 443
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: meteo-secret

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: meteo-svc
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
      name: https
  selector:
    app: meteo


    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
#    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-access-log: "true"
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
  name: meteo-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: meteotravel.ru
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: meteo-svc
          servicePort: 443
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - meteotravel.ru
#    secretName: cafe-secret


This is default backend

    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
  labels:
    k8s-app: default-http-backend
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: default-http-backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: default-http-backend
        # Any image is permissable as long as:
        # 1. It serves a 404 page at /
        # 2. It serves 200 on a /healthz endpoint
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
#        resources:
#          limits:
#            cpu: 100m
#            memory: 200Mi
#          requests:
#            cpu: 100m
#            memory: 200Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    k8s-app: default-http-backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    k8s-app: default-http-backend

And it is code for nodeport service for ingress-controller because I use bare metal cluster

    apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

---
```

But it works strange
It overload 1 node that is a router-mode(ingress controller daemon)
And worker nodes don't work

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to offload one router node and load worker nodes.
On scheme???from weave scope I see that ingress controller overload

I get the following results of ab -n 1000000 -k -c 5000 
[image]
I think it is so slow It will be greate if it works as simple tcp proxy
with minimum of resources

Comment: Did you use any cloud provider or it is installed on premise?

Comment: No I use only virtual machines created by VirtualBox

Comment: I disable buffering and it works

Comment: But Ingress controller is also work hard for ab -n 1000000 -c 5000 -k. I get load 300% for ingress-controller. Why ?

Comment: looks like you have only 1 endpoint and as I know you not using cloud provider which usually provide external load balancer which decrease average to one node. Now all you traffic processed by 1 node and you see huge load, try to make load balancer (external - outside kubernetes) which will send traffic to all your nodes

Comment: Nick it is impossible. I wan't to check is my ingress controller only transfer traffic to worker nodes or it make ssl termination also. How to check this? I can't use external load balancer. Only use many ingress controllers and many ip's in DNS A rules for same domain and different IP's

Comment: it should not work because `#    secretName: cafe-secret` you comment the cert, and you can check ssl termination by logs from your app

Comment: Nick I found example of config here https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/1854?fbclid=IwAR2Pzv7EhRsIIyXdZ0ab-DGO11U-s_iqBp1Rk3AVOeykPNIKJH7ED8uRP4M#issuecomment-256623830 and there is no secret there. How to do this I don't see any logs in ingress controller Only this    8 controller.go:190] Backend successfully reloaded.
I1212 11:15:12.364668       8 controller.go:202] Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second.
[12/Dec/2018:11:15:13 +0000]TCP200000.000
I1212 11:15:52.410426       8 status.go:148] new leader elected: nginx-ingress-controller-b89kt

Comment: I don't want to terminate ssl in ingress controller. I wan't to use it as bypass. And make termination at backends, which are simple nginx servers with ssl certs and keys

Comment: Now I get this errors during ab test  SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection

 and in the log of ingress controller       
2018/12/12 17:23:43 [debug] 3784#3784: *442252 http lua finalize fake request: 0, a:1, c:1
2018/12/12 17:23:43 [debug] 3784#3784: *442252 http lua fake request count:1
2018/12/12 17:23:43 [debug] 3784#3784: *442252 http lua close fake request
2018/12/12 17:23:43 [debug] 3784#3784: *442252 lua request cleanup: forcible=0
2018/12/12 17:23:43 [debug] 3784#3784: *442252 http lua close fake http connection 000055FB09550FF0

Comment: I think it works so slow that I decide to not use ingress-nginx